# Not able to use Kotlin Extension Function written in common in iOS as Swift Extension

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, extension-methods, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a Kotlin Multiplatform project setup with Android & cocoapods for iOS.

I have a file `Extensions.kt` in `commonMain/src` with the following function:

```
fun String.isValidEmail(): Boolean {
    return validate(ValidatorRegex.EMAIL)
}
```

I am able to access this function in Android as a `String` extension:

```
"abcd@gmail.com".isValidEmail()
```

But in iOS using Swift, I need to call it as a static method of another class:

```
ExtensionsKt.isValidEmail("abcd@gmail.com")
```

It should convert that `commonMain/src` method to a Swift extension of `String` instead of a class with a static method.

**Am I missing any configuration?**

Comment: there is no direct function call like in swift you need to create a class then call or make a extension of `String`.

Comment: In Swift, you do not call extensions like that. 
In Kotlin extensions are resolved statically, but Swift they are not.
It may be;
"abcd@gmail.com".ExtensionsKt.isValidEmail()
or;
"abcd@gmail.com".isValidEmail()

Comment: @EmreSURK , I also want kotlin-multiplatform to convert that code for iOS in such a way so I can use it like.
"abcd@gmail.com".isValidEmail() 

but right now it is converting the code as below.
ExtensionsKt.isValidEmail("abcd@gmail.com")

Hope you understand what I am saying.

Comment: I do not think you can use Extensions in that way. In Swift, you can also use computed parameters in extension and you can use it in that way; "abcd@gmail.com".ExtensionsKt.isValidEmail. It is a variable, not a function anymore. I don't know how to create it with Kotlin and if it is suitable for you but that is the way in Swift Extensions. You can also create a static func and use it in your vay but it is not an extension anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing everything right here. Unfortunately, this option is not available for now. Extensions conversion may be performed correctly for some classes, but Swift's `String` is not the one. This is a known inconvenience, and K/N team is working hard to make it better.

Comment: Is there any open issue to get progress updates?

Comment: IIRC, there was not a specific one for that.

Comment: Wonder how hard they are working to "resolve" the issue. After all it has been 3 years

Answer (score 0):

It's how kotlin/native works with platform classes - created in kotlin extensions visible as static functions. But for better Swift API you can use plugin https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-kswift that generate Swift code wrapper of Kotlin with better API